# ng-show button if time is 2hrs greater than current time

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angular.js to hide/show a button based on a specified time. I only want to show the button if the specified time is less than the current time -2hrs.

Controller.js:

```
$scope.showclose = function (time) {
    var time=new Date(time);
    var maxtime= new Date();
    maxtime.setHours(maxtime.getHours() - 2);
    return (time <= maxtime)
};
```

index.html:

```
 <button ng-show="showclose(order.time)" style="padding:3px; height: 15px; font-size:9px;"  onclick="close()"  class="btn btn-primary closebutton" ng-click="close(order)" ><b>X</b></button>
```

On loading the page with the data, any records having the time less than the maxdate shows the button.

The maxdate is calculated based on the current time so it is constantly changing.
The button is not appearing when a record has its time grater than the maxdate on load, although as time goes by it eventually becomes less than the maxdate. I want the button to appear when it eventually becomes less without having to refresh the page.

Any ideas please?

Thanks

Comment: First of all, you don't have to call close function from both `onclick` and `ng-click`. And please don't use `<b>` tag for bold! Using CSS for this is more standards compliant.

Comment: thanks for your feedback. Any ideas on the actual issue i'm encountering please?

Comment: Care to share how `order.time` looks like?

Comment: I think you mean 'current time is 2hrs greater than time when user landed on website'

Answer (score 0):

Right now nothing makes your function to reevaluate when time comes. You need to somehow set a timer that will update visibility later. [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/u09Eq0m8dEMKWJH6MJjs?p=preview).

For example, you can create custom directive.

```
<button show-in="{{2*60*60*1000}}" class="btn btn-primary">In 2 hours</button>

app.directive('showIn', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      showIn: '@'  
    },
    link: function(scope, el) {
      var delay = parseInt(scope.showIn) // milliseconds

      if(delay > 0) { 
        el.addClass('hidden'); // assuming you have bootstrap

        var pending = $timeout(function() { // set timer
          el.removeClass('hidden')
          pending = null
        }, delay)

        scope.$on('$destroy', function() { // clear timer when element destroyed
          if(pending) {
            $timeout.cancel(pending)
          }
        })
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I guess *const* is a new ES 6 feature and thus not compatible with all browsers? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yep, I've used to it :) Switching back to es5 is hard. :)

Answer (score 0):

A very simple (and not necessarily the most performant) solution is an `$interval`.

```
$scope.showButton = false;

$interval(function() {
   var time=new Date(time);
   var maxtime= new Date();
   maxtime.setHours(maxtime.getHours() - 2);
   $scope.showButton = time <= maxtime;
}, 1000;

<button ng-show="showButton"></button>
```

The problem is, Angular doesn't digest automatically, when time passes by. It only digests when an event occurs, like a user click, a http request ends etc. An interval will also cause a new digest cycle to begin.

Comment: Won't this run digest loop like every second for no reason? For every button.

Comment: Yes, it will. Simplicity against performance. In many cases it will be just enough; if the OP is writing a very complex app, than he should probably try something better.

Answer (score 0):

Using pretty much the same approach as @Yury Tarabanko's answer. but in a slightly different manner.

Created a timer that will hide the object when it is older than two hours from current time.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout){
  
  $scope.order = {
    "time": "July 5, 2016 10:54:00",
    "shown": true
  }
  
  $scope.laterThanTwoHoursFrom = function(time) {
    var time = new Date(time);
    var maxtime= new Date();    
    maxtime.setHours(maxtime.getHours() - 2);
    
    if (time >= maxtime){
      $timeout(function(){
        return true
      }, time.getTime() - maxtime.getTime());
    }
    else {
      return true
    }
  };
  
  $scope.close = function(order) {
    order.shown = false;
  };
  
});
```

```css
.close-btn {
  padding: 0px 3px; 
  height: 30px; 
  font-size: 9px;
  line-height: 25px;
 }

.order.closed {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    
    <div class="order" 
      ng-class="{'closed' : !order.shown}" 
      ng-hide="laterThanTwoHoursFrom(order.time)">
      
        <p>Order information<p>
      
        <button class="close-btn" ng-click="close(order)">
          <strong>X</strong>
        </button>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```